# Max count of users

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want use Free plan for sending push-notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging.

On "pricing" page I found info about 2kk invocations. Is it count of all requests for my project?

And what is max count of devices for free plan? Without any authentication using SMS on mobile number. 
For example, can I use 2kk invocations for sending notification to 100k different devices?

Comment: There are no limit on sending notification

Comment: @tuledev thanks, but what is limit "invocations"?

Comment: They're function invocations.

Comment: I'm unclear exactly what you're looking at the console.  Could you describe in more detail what you're reading, or maybe include a screenshot and point out what you see?

Comment: @DougStevenson I see this link: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/
And below, in section "blaze plan calculator" we have group "Cloud Functions". What is "Cloud functions"? Sending push-notifiactions is it "cloud function"? 
And I really can send push-notifications without any limit on infinity count of devices?

Comment: Cloud Functions limits are not at all related to Cloud Messaging limits. Your question is asking about Messaging.  Messaging is free and unlimited.  Cloud Functions is not.  You might want to follow up with others on your project if you don't know what Cloud Functions is, as it's basically impossible to invoke them completely by accident.

Answer (score 0):

How said @tuledev and @DougStevenson, messages really free and it's not related with cloud functions. 
Thanks!